# How do I connect a BLE device from Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi4

Using this simple code:

```
from bluepy import btle
import time
import codecs
import logging
import bmsstate

OUTGOING_HEADER = b'\xaa\x55\x90\xeb'
INCOMING_HEADER = b'\x55\xaa\xeb\x90'

MAX_COMMAND_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 5
MAX_STATE_LIFE_SECCONDS = 5

COMMAND_REQ_EXTENDED_RECORD = 0x96
COMMAND_REQ_DEVICE_INFO = 0x97
COMMAND_REQ_CHARGE_SWITCH = 0x1d
COMMAND_REQ_DISCHARGE_SWITCH = 0x1e

RESPONSE_ACK = 0xc8
RESPONSE_EXTENDED_RECORD = 0x01
RESPONSE_CELL_DATA = 0x02
RESPONSE_DEVICE_INFO_RECORD = 0x03

class JkBMS(btle.DefaultDelegate):

    def __init__(self, bt_mac):
        btle.DefaultDelegate.__init__(self)
        self.bt_mac = bt_mac
        self.name = bt_mac
        self.connected = False

    def logDebug(self, text):
        logging.debug(f'JkBMS {self.name}: {text}')

    def logInfo(self, text):
        logging.info(f'JkBMS {self.name}: {text}')

    def logWarn(self, text):
        logging.warning(f'JkBMS {self.name}: {text}')

    def logError(self, text):
        logging.error(f'JkBMS {self.name}: {text}')

    def initialize(self):
        self.sendCommand(COMMAND_REQ_DEVICE_INFO)
        self.sendCommand(COMMAND_REQ_EXTENDED_RECORD)


    def connect(self):
        if self.connected:
            return

        self.incomingData = bytearray()
        self.device = btle.Peripheral(None)
        self.device.withDelegate(self)
        attempts = 0
        conn = False

        while not conn:
            attempts += 1
            if attempts > 2:
                self.logError(f'cannot connect to JK BMS at {self.bt_mac}')
                exit()
            try:
                self.device.connect(self.bt_mac)
                conn = True
            except Exception as err:
                self.logError(f'connection failed to {self.bt_mac}, re-try')
                print(f"Unexpected {err=}, {type(err)=}")
                time.sleep(1)
                continue

JK_BMS_MAC3 = "C8:47:8C:E4:57:FB"
jkbms3 = jkbms.JkBMS(JK_BMS_MAC3)
jkbms3.initialize()
```

Breaks with exception, cannot connect:

> ERROR:root:JkBMS C8:47:8C:E4:57:FB: connection failed to
> C8:47:8C:E4:57:FB, re-try Unexpected err=BTLEDisconnectError('Failed
> to connect to peripheral C8:47:8C:E4:57:FB, addr type: public',
> {'rsp': ['stat'], 'state': ['disc'], 'mtu': [0], 'sec': ['low']}),
> type(err)=<class 'bluepy.btle.BTLEDisconnectError'>

The address (C8:47:8C:E4:57:FB) is correct, I can see it listed when using "sudo hcitool lescan". And I can connect fine using my phone / app.

What's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to connect using `bluetoothctl` on the RPi command line?

Comment: I have checked using "sudo systemctl status bluetooth" and the device gets listet with "bluetoothctl scan on". But pairing it using "bluetoothctl pair xxx" fails, it says "not available". But I am not sure if it must be paired at all, because it is BLE, not bluetooth ...

Comment: using `bluetoothctl connect` fails as well

Comment: Then it's highly likely not to be the library or your Python code. Are there any error messages in `bluetoothctl`. Or monitoring with `sudo btmon`